# XCOPY /exclude reference a ext file that is not in the working directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, xcopy

I have tried to reference the directory of the text file after `/exclusions`.

What is wrong with my syntax?

```
xcopy "J:\Common\NY SERTIFIKATBANK\18 Buoyancy Reports\Nav Lights\534515"   "534515" /I /y /r /exclusions:"K:\Temp\TO UPLOAD\0 BIJANs FILES\100 BATcreator\exclusions.txt"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What is wrong with my syntax?

```
xcopy "J:\Common\NY SERTIFIKATBANK\18 Buoyancy Reports\Nav Lights\534515"   "534515" /I /y /r /exclusions:"K:\Temp\TO UPLOAD\0 BIJANs FILES\100 BATcreator\exclusions.txt"
```

`xcopy` does not have a `/exclusions` option.

It uses `/exclude` which is **not** a text file, but a list of files to exclude.

---

#### Syntax

> ```
> /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
> ```
>
> - The files can each contain one or more full or partial pathnames to be excluded.
> - When any of these match any part of the absolute path of a SOURCE file, then 
>          that file will be excluded.
> - For example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
>          all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
>          .obj extension respectively.

Source [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.